# Unable to connect to sshuttle

Tags: python, proxy, vercel, inet

I am getting the following error when I try running sshuttle using `sshuttle -r hopper 10.0.0.0/8`. I am on sshuttle@1.1.1 and python@3.10.7
Tried reinstalling sshuttle, python, switching network, but no luck.

```
arjun@arjun ~ % sshuttle -r hopper 10.10.0.0/16 -v
Starting sshuttle proxy (version 1.1.1).
c : Starting firewall manager with command: ['/usr/bin/sudo', '-p', '[local sudo] Password: ', '/usr/bin/env', 'PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/sshuttle/1.1.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/sshuttle/1.1.1/libexec/bin/python3.10', '//usr/local/bin/sshuttle', '-v', '--method', 'auto', '--firewall']
[local sudo] Password: 
fw: Starting firewall with Python version 3.10.7
fw: ready method name nft.
c : IPv6 enabled: Using default IPv6 listen address ::1
c : Method: nft
c : IPv4: on
c : IPv6: on
c : UDP : off (not available with nft method)
c : DNS : off (available)
c : User: off (not available with nft method)
c : Subnets to forward through remote host (type, IP, cidr mask width, startPort, endPort):
c :   (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, '10.10.0.0', 16, 0, 0)
c : Subnets to exclude from forwarding:
c :   (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, '127.0.0.1', 32, 0, 0)
c :   (<AddressFamily.AF_INET6: 30>, '::1', 128, 0, 0)
c : TCP redirector listening on ('::1', 12300, 0, 0).
c : TCP redirector listening on ('127.0.0.1', 12300).
c : Starting client with Python version 3.10.7
c : Connecting to server...
Add public key /Users/arjun/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to instance i-182a139c99cbba5b1 for 60 seconds
Start ssm session to instance i-182a139c99cbba5b1
 s: Running server on remote host with /usr/bin/python3 (version 3.6.9)
 s: latency control setting = True
 s: auto-nets:False
c : Connected to server.
fw: setting up.
fw: nft add table inet sshuttle-ipv6-12300 
Error: File /Users/arjun/inet does not exist.
    at Job.emitDependency (/Users/arjun/node_modules/@vercel/nft/out/node-file-trace.js:280:23)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Object.nodeFileTrace (/Users/arjun/node_modules/@vercel/nft/out/node-file-trace.js:32:5)
    at async cli (/Users/arjun/node_modules/@vercel/nft/out/cli.js:28:58)
fw: nft add chain inet sshuttle-ipv6-12300 prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to delete the `/Users/arjun/node_modules` folder. Still don't know what was interfering with sshuttle, my guess is it was nvm.